# TcpClient reconnect to an already open connection

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm working with TcpClient to communicate with a hardware device.
The communication to the device may drop for a period of 30 seconds or so, as part of a testing process. This is fine and sometimes intended.

The problem begins when I'm sending data to the device while communication is down. Because I'm using TcpClient, I'm getting an IO exception and the connection is dropped. The connection at the device side is still open though. 
How can I:

- Reconnect to the open connection at the device? creating a new TcpClient will create a new connection at the device side and is unwanted...
- Perhaps Make TCP retransmissions take longer then 30 seconds ?(windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

Your best method is to exchange a session identifier or have some other way to track connections and have code to handle resumes. You can increase the value of your [SendTimeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.sendtimeout%28v=vs.100%29), but the receive side could still end up timiing out the connection on its end.

You cannot reopen a specific connection with TcpClient once it is closed. The only other way you might do this (raw sockets code) seems to me to be more trouble than it's worth.